# При установке Android Studio возникла проблема с HAXM

Tags: android-studio, install

HAXM у меня есть, я его удалял (до этого тоже были проблемы с Android Studio, поэтому пытался установить его с нуля), но после восстановил, подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне делать в этой ситуации
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конфигурацию железа укажите. Очень похоже что HAXM просто им не поддерживается.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, процессор intel(R) 2.80GHz  Core(TM) i5 CPU 2.80GHz, тип системы 64-разрядная операционная система, процессор X64, оперативная память 8 Гб

Comment: В BIOS все включено? VT-x и может еще чего... 
https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows

Comment: @ Eugene Krivenja, Hyper-V было отключено

Comment: @ Eugene Krivenja, Hyper-V включил, но запустить эмулятор всё ещё не получается

Comment: Eugene Krivenja, попробовал переустановить эмулятор, получил следующую ошибку: Unable to install Intel HAXM
HAXM device is not found.
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that HAXM is installed properly. Try disabling 3rd party security software if the problem still occurs.
Для включения VT-x, как я понял, нужно поставить галочку на Hyper-V, это я сделал, но не помогло

Comment: @ Eugene Krivenja, попробовал сделать то же самое с отключённым антивирусом, тоже не помогло

Comment: @ Eugene Krivenja, может быть что-то сломалось при удалении и восстановлении папки intel?

Comment: hyper-v как раз наоборот нужно непременно выключить, это конкурирующая технология виртуализации и вместе им не жить. А включить вам надо аппаратную "родную" виртуализацию Intel в настройках BIOS вашей материнской платы (из винды она вообще не включается)

Comment: Hyper-V и VT-x это разные вещи. @pavlofff прав, Hyper-V надо отключить.